# Why did copying my Windows 10 partition to a new location cause my desktop to flash constantly?

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning, gpt

Would simply moving my windows partition to an earlier location on the disk, and running bcdedit to create a new boot entry, be expected to cause any problems?

Here's what happened:

I had a windows partition that was near the end of the disk (~3tb to ~4tb on a 4tb disk) and I wanted to expand it, so I copied it to free space near the beginning of the (4tb gpt) disk using AOMEI Partition Assistant.

Then I used bcdedit to add a boot entry for the newly copied partition.

- It seemed to start up fine, but upon logging in, the screen started flashing.
- Explorer.exe was crashing several times per second.
- It was hard to do much but I managed to taskkill explorer.exe to stop the flashing and look at the system logs.
- The explorer.exe error is in twinui.dll.
- There are also errors popping up about attempted memory access to very low addresses like 0x00000000008.
- I rebooted to a recovery console command prompt and "ran sfc /scannow". sfc got to 100% verifying and then said "Windows Resource Protection could not perform the required operation."

I can boot from the original partition without any trouble.

Please don't bother telling me I need to reinstall windows.

Comment: Reboot several times, wait 5 minutes before each reboot, are the issues still there?

Comment: What's that supposed to do?

Comment: Did you do a sector by sector copy or a quick copy?  I am not super familiar with that particular partition tool, but my guess would be a protected file wasn't copied bit-for-bit.  This could potentially lead to issues depending on how much wasn't copied accurately.

Comment: Aha! Great thinking! I did a quick copy. I will try again with a sector-by-sector tonight and post results here.

Comment: I just tried again with a sector by sector copy. Same result. Back to the flashing desktop.

Comment: Other things I've tried that make no difference: safe mode, disabling all startup items, adding a new user.

Comment: "What's that supposed to do? " I may solve your issue, but will not know until you try it.

Comment: @Moab I've restarted plenty of times.

Comment: What about backup/restore? Indeed two long operations are involved but do we exactly know if every file needs to be copied one to one? Maybe some "links" are not completely relative?

Comment: @snayob hunh?   -